# Optimizing for Outlook Web Access: image width 100%

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-app

I'm formatting an email template with an image that stretches to 100% of the width of the parent table. This looks and works great in all email providers I've tried, except for Outlook Web Access. It's not recognizing the height property defined by the table, the table row, or the image itself. It stretches the image height almost infinitely. Any thoughts on how to force Outlook web access to display the image properly? Here's what I'm working with:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" border="0" text-decoration="none" style="min-width: 100%">
<table width="100%" border="0" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding:15px  link="#fff" vlink="#fff" alink="#fff" >
  <tr valign="bottom" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="4" colspan="4" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="207" rowspan="2" valign="top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><img src="image/header-left.png" width="259" height="69" alt="logo"></td>
    <td width="157" height="29" colspan="2" align="right" valign="top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><img src="image/header-right.png" width="156" height="69" alt="right image"></td></tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" height="80" rowspan="2" valign="top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td height="80" max-height="80" colspan="2" rowspan="0" align="right" valign="top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-height:80px;"><img src="image/header-center.png" alt="bottom middle image" width="100%" height="80" style="max-height="80"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Due to outlook not supporting display:block you images are treating in image so will not strech